# Visual Studio Compiler Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I was making a simple DLL as a test in visual studio 2010. 
Here is the code for SimpleCPP.cpp

```
#include iostream
#include "SimpleH.h"

namespace nmspace
{

void myclass::Crap()

{

    std::cout << "Test." << std::endl;

    }

}
```

Here is the code for the header file

```
    #include <iostream>
    namespace nmspace
{
        class myclass
    {
    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) void Crap();
   };
}
```

My problem is when I compile I get an error that says that visual studio can't find the file SimpleDLLd.dll. In closer inspection I see that when the program is compiling visual studio adds a d to the release files. For example when the DLL is supposed to be SimpleDLL.dll (The project name is SimpleDLL) visual studio adds a d and outputs SimpleDlld.dll. I tried doing the same thing in another project and it did the same thing. I then proceeded to Visual Studio 2013 and copy and pasted the contents of the cpp and header files into new files and surprisingly got the same exact result as Visual Studio 2010. How would I fix this error? Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Check the name of the build target in your project file settings. The name of the resulting file should be in the
*Linker->General->Output File*
setting in the project which is usually *$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)* by default.

Comment: Everything is normal there.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What value is there when the project is in release mode?

Comment: $(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)

Comment: In the project properties whats the value of the _General->TargetName_ setting?

Comment: It said $(ProjectName)d but then I removed the d and Visual Studio now can't find "SimpleDLL.dll"(quotes not included).

Comment: There hasn't been a reply in 6 days. Bumping for reply.

Comment: In the output folder, what files are being generated then?

Comment: In the comment above I explained that. It couldn't find SimpleDLL.dll even though there is no added characters.

Comment: Yes you did, but that alone isn't a useful clue. If all the settings appear correct, then when you build _something_ is being built as a result of that. Knowing what is built would help a lot. Also if you have the exact error from the output log and the couple lines before that, that would also be enlightening

Comment: I told what was built, all there was, was an error message: http://imgur.com/AU4hQsT and nothing shows up in the output logs.

Comment: There hasn't been a reply in 10 days. Bumping for reply.

Comment: There hasn't been a reply in 19 days. Bumping for reply.